# Is this inequality in $L^2$ true?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, hilbert-spaces, functional-inequalities

Suppose we have functions $f \in L^2([0,T],H^{-1}),g \in L^2([0,T],H^{1})$, i would like to see how can i get the following inequality

\begin{equation}
\left|(f,g)_{L^2([0,T] \times \mathbb{T})}\right| \leq ||f||_{ L^2([0,T],H^{-1})}||g||_{L^2([0,T],H^{1})}
\end{equation}

where $\mathbb{T} = \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. I'm trying to solve this for a specific problem in which i have not realized how to do that, so i would like to know if in general i can get that inequality, if u think that some info is missing or needed, i could show you the specific problem that i have.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $f$ merely belongs to $L^2([0,T], H^{-1})$,  you cannot write $(f,g)_{L^2([0,T] \times \mathbb T)}$. This would require $f \in L^2([0,T], L^2)$.

Comment: @gerw And if we suppose $f \in L^2([0,T],L^2)$ how do we get that ?

Comment: Then, this is a simple consequence of the fact how you interpret $f$ as a function in $L^2(H^{-1})$. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f \in L^2([0,T] \times \mathbb T)$ be given.
Then, we typically identify $f$ with the functional
$\hat f \in L^2(0,T; H^{-1})$, which is defined via
$$
\langle \hat f, g\rangle_{L^2(H^{-1}), L^2(H^1)}
:=
\int_0^T \int_\Omega f(t,x) g(t,x)\,\mathrm dx \, \mathrm{d}t
=
(f, g)_{L^2([0,T]\times \mathbb T)}
$$
for all $g \in L^2(0,T,H^1)$.
Similarly, one identifies $f(t) \in L^2$ with $\hat f(t) \in H^{-1}$
defined via
$$
\langle \hat f(t), g\rangle_{H^{-1},H^1} = \int_\Omega f(t,x) \, g(t,x) \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
for all $g \in H^1$.
Thus,
$$
(f, g)_{L^2([0,T]\times \mathbb T)}
=
\int_0^T \langle \hat f(t), g(t)\rangle_{H^{-1},H^1} \, \mathrm{d}t.
$$
This last identity (together with the identification of $f$ and $\hat f$) yields your inequality:
$$
|(f, g)_{L^2([0,T]\times \mathbb T)}|
\le
\int_0^T \|\hat f(t)\|_{H^{-1}} \, \|g(t)\|_{H^1} \, \mathrm{d}t
\le
\| \hat f\|_{L^2(H^{-1})} \, \|g\|_{L^2(H^1)}.
$$

Comment: I really don't see how The last identity gives me The inequality. Could u give a bit more insight please?

Comment: Just use the definition of the $H^{-1}$ norm and Cauchy-Schwarz. I have edited the answer.